# QGIS action Python recover id after paste

Tags: pyqgis

I have 3 layers:
a point layer (1) with id,
a polygon layers origin  (3) with id_1.
a polygon layer destin (2) with id, id_1 et id_p.

I want to copy the polygons from layer 3 (which I select with the mouse) to layer 2 (id_1 = 10 et 11 for example) and I want the copied polygons to take the id of the layer point (1) selected (id = 2 for example).

My script allows you to do these steps except the last one.

Does anyone have an idea?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
   ## ETAPE 1 COPIE LES POLYGON ORIGIN VERS DESTNATION
    o = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon_origin")[0]
    d = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon_dest")[0]
    poly_o = o.selectedFeatures()
    iface.actionCopyFeatures().trigger()
    iface.setActiveLayer(d)
    d.startEditing()
    iface.actionPasteFeatures().trigger()
    d.commitChanges()
    #### ETAPE 2 : COPIE LES ID DU POINT VERS POLYG DEST
    point = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("point")[0]
    p = point.selectedFeatures()
    for feature in p :
        id_s = (feature["id"])
        print(id_s)
    dest_s = iface.activeLayer() 
    iface.showAttributeTable(dest_s)
    active_layer.startEditing()
    field_name = 'id_p'
    for f in dest_s.getFeatures():
        f[field_name] = id_s
        dest_s.updateFeature(f)
        dest_s.commitChanges()
```

Comment: If you found a solution you should answer your question rather than edit your question.

Comment: @Louis Cottereau (thank you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I share a solution (that I found alone):**

```
o = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon_origin")[0]
d = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon_dest")[0]
poly_o = o.selectedFeatures()
iface.actionCopyFeatures().trigger()
iface.setActiveLayer(d)
d.startEditing()
iface.actionPasteFeatures().trigger()
point = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("point")[0]
p = point.selectedFeatures()
for feature in p :
    id_s = (feature["id"])
field_name = 'id_p'
new_value = id_s
field_idx = d.fields().indexOf('id_p')
d.startEditing() 
for f in d.selectedFeatures():
    f[field_name] = id_s
    d.updateFeature(f)
d.commitChanges()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]